# How to put a command and a field into one column kendoui grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to put a command and a field together in my column. Currently, my solution is define a template as below

```
var commentsTemplate = "<input class='comments-button' type='image' src='images/comments_button.png' />#: COMMENTS #";
```

Is it possible to put a kendo-ui command and field into one column?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A command column will render a button in the column cells that triggers the command. If you need something else beside that you need to use a template.